# Parallel Programming using C Language

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I'm taking a parallel programming course. I have an assignment to make a thread using C language with N = 8. I have the source code but when I compile and run it only reaches N = 6.

So far, I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 8
#define M 1000

int index = 0;

bool checkIndex(int index, int arr[M]);
void addIndex(int index, int arr[M]);

int main() {
    int a[M];
    int b[M];
    int c[M];
    int arrIndex[M];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        a[i] = rand();
        b[i] = rand();
        c[i] = 0;
        arrIndex[i] = -1;
    }

    // #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("%d: ", i);

        for (int y = i*2; y < M; y+=N) {
            if (!checkIndex(y, arrIndex)) {
                addIndex(y, arrIndex);
                c[y] = a[y] + b[y];
                printf("%d ", y);
            }

            y++;
            if (!checkIndex(y, arrIndex)) {
                addIndex(y, arrIndex);
                c[y] = a[y] + b[y];
                printf("%d ", y);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

bool checkIndex(int value, int arr[M]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void addIndex(int value, int arr[M]) {
    arr[index++] = value;
}
```

The desired output is:
0: 0, 1, 9, 10, ...
1: 2, 3, 11, 12, ...
2: 4, 5, 13, 14, ...
.
.
7:14, 15, 23, 24, ...

I would really appreciate if someone were to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Now with the `#pragma omp` commented and there's no parallelism, does it work then? Do you get the expected result?

Comment: To make it simpler to test and debug, please don't use random values, use actual hard-coded values as "input" where the outcome is well-known and can be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have UB in two places.

First of all, `y` can be out of bounds in the second `c[y] = a[y] + b[y]`. In the first thread (i=0), `y` will be 999 and then 1000 (following `y++`) in the final iteration of its loop.

Secondly, `index` can go out of bounds in `arr[index++] = value`.
You might *assume* that this cannot happen because `value` has a domain of only 1000 values,
but due to the fact that `y` goes out of bounds (see above), there are actually 1001 possible values.

This clobbers the stack and can cause the program to crash.